# MySQL binary strings and charset

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, binary

In MySQL, can binary strings (BINARY, VARBINARY and BLOB) have a CHARSET so bytes used per character are different for each CHARSET as in non-binary strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. That'd defeat the purpose of the binary data types. They're meant for data that cannot ever be charset-translated. E.g. you save .jpg images in your DB. If the raw binary data was charset-translated, the jpg would be totally corrupted.

If you want charsets, then use `varchar`, `text`, etc...

Comment: Then, if I store the string "añäà" (or with chinese symbols) in a binary data type, how is it treated? I mean, what is the relation between the character I type and the binary representation? Because ALL existing characters can't be encoded in a single byte. Thanks.

Comment: so? that's why it's binary data. you're telling mysql that whatever bytes go into the field are just that - a sequence of bytes. if your charset actually is multi-byte, that's therefore irrelevant to mysql. two bytes representing one UTF-16 char are just two bytes.

Comment: Yep, I understand that, but what happens if I inset the string "abc"  in a binary(3) field from my command line and my mysql connection has a default charset that takes 3 bytes per character? Will the data be truncated?

Comment: nothing. it's binary data. mysql won't do ANY translations on it. you put in 3bytes, and 3 bytes will come out. 3 bytes will also get sent "over the wire" back to the client. how those 3 bytes are treated on the client is not mysql's concern.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is something I don't catch... Imagine that I have a keyboard with 300 keys, if I write the key number 300 into the string, how is this handled? Because a byte ranges from 0 to 255...

Comment: assuming ascii, your `300` is actually `0x33 0x30 0x30` for bytes.you're not storing an integer representation of 300, you're storing the bytes representing the characters `3`, `0`, and `0`. now, if you convert that string 300 into an integer 300, then you have `0x01 0x2c` for bytes, and those bytes go into the database EXACTLY like that. They also come OUT of the database exactly like that. how those bytes are interpreted by the client is not mysql's problem. if you uploaded from a bigt-endian system, and downloaded to a little-endian system, you'd get 3090 decimal back out.

Comment: *Sorry, I didn't mean the ```300``` literally. I mean, imagine that I have a symbol A in my keyboard that is represented as ```0x30``` ```0x30```. If I write a string containing 3 symbols AAA, that is, 6 bytes. If I set this string into a binary(3) field, are these bytes truncated?

Comment: you're way overthinking this. mysql couldn't care less what the bytes you're inserting represent. that's why they're binary data types. you stuff in 1 byte, mysql saves one byte; you stuff in 200 gigabytes, mysql saves 200 gigabytes. what those bytes represent is UTTERLY ignored by mysql. if you stuff in more bytes than you told mysql the field should hold, your bytes will be truncated to the max size of the field.

Comment: Ok, I think that I've finally understood it